# Insert, update and Delete issues in Phonegap for SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, cordova

I want to insert update and delete the data of the table in SQLite using Phonegap, I know the way of doing it, but the issue is that whenever I am trying to insert the same record twice it is giving me the error, Which is perfect but when I am deleting the same row twice its entering the success function everytime Why so?? Same is the case for Update function, and I am not getting why this is happening , am i doing any silly misatkes in the code? Please help me
Update function

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
    var abc= "UPDATE table_name SET a= ? WHERE id = ?";
    tx.executeSql(abc, [a, id],function SuccessUpdate(tx,result){
        alert("success");
        alert("Last inserted ID = " + result.insertId);
    },
    function errorUpdate(error){
    alert("Error processing SQL : "+error.code);
    });
    });
```

Delete Function

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
    var abc= "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=?";
    tx.executeSql(abc, [id], function(){
    alert("success");
    });
    }, function errorCB(err){
        alert("error");
       console.warn("Error processing SQL: "+err.code); 
    }, function (){
        alert("success");
    });
```

This question might sound silly but I dont know why is this happening, I searched about this but couldnt find anything useful

Comment: What should happen instead?

Comment: I guess it should give me a error @CL. dont u think so? because I am trying to delete a record which has been already deleted ,or same the case with the updation, deleted record can not be updated so it should give me the error.

Comment: @user3060230 You should be using the `result.rowsAffected`. If it is less than 1, it means the update/delete was unsuccessful. The `result.insertId` should be used for INSERT statments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how SQL works.
The UPDATE and DELETE statements affect all rows that match the WHERE clause; this could be no, or one, or multiple rows.

To number or affected rows can be read afterwards with the `rowsAffected` attribute of the result object:

```
tx.executeSql("UPDATE ...", [...], function SuccessUpdate(tx,result){
    if (result.rowsAffected < 1)
        ...
}
```

Comment: So you mean that it will always gicve me success even if there is no such entry?

Answer (score 1):

It's because DELETE doesn't return an error if column exists and only the row wasn't found.

You can do this on Android SQLiteDatabase:

```
int result = myDB.delete("table_name", "WHERE name=?", new String[] { "Jack" });

if (result == 0)
    Log.e("myDatabase", "Nothing was deleted (row not found)");
```

Variable result here holds the number of affected rows as per [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

EDIT:

Sorry, didn't notice this is for Phonegap.

But as per [this source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_sqlresultset_sqlresultset.md.html) you can *try* this:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
    var abc= "DELETE table_name SET a= ? WHERE id = ?";
    tx.executeSql(abc, [a, id],function SuccessUpdate(tx,result){
        if (!result.rowsAffected) {
            alert("Nothing was deleted");
        } else {
            alert("Delete successful");
        }
    },
    function errorUpdate(error){
            alert("Error processing SQL : "+error.code);
    });
});
```

Note: I haven't tested this, as I have no experience with this framework, sorry.

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Comment: This is for the core android I am asking for the solution using Phonegap